# Let $a$ and $b$ be roots of $x^2-4x+1=0$ then what is $a^b(b^a)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, roots

Let $a$ and $b$ be roots of $x^2-4x+1=0$ then what is $a^b(b^a)$

I always worked with $ S $ and $P$  but for  this sentence $a^b(b^a)$ no have idea.

Comment: Hint: $a^b \cdot b^a = (a^{ab})^{1/a} \cdot (b^{ab})^{1/b}$.

Comment: @EkeneE. Then. $ab =1$ so we have $a^{1/a} b^{1/b}$ now ?

Comment: @amirhosseinbehbodi Your roots have the particular property, $a = 1/b$. Then its just a matter of substitution

Comment: The quadratic formula gives $a=u+v$, $b=u-v$. Then $(a^b)(b^a)=a^{u-v}b^{u+v}=(b/a)^v=b^{2v}$. I don't see how to simplify this further even knowing $u$ and $v$. [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=a%3D2%2Bsqrt%283%29%2C+b%3D2-sqrt%283%29%2C+z%3D%28a%5Eb%29*%28b%5Ea%29%2C+t%3Db%5E2) seems to agree.